# Error - Sitecore is configured for item serialization but it's creating YAML files

Tags: configuration, serialization

I'm using Sitecore 9.3 and when I try to serialize an item by **Developer > Serialize Tree**, the
item generated always has the extension ".yaml". However, I'd like the extension ".item".

I've set up the Serialization Type at file "Sitecore.Serialization.config", but didn't work.

[image: Serialization Config]

Is there anything more that I need to do? Could someone help me, please?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your showconfig.aspx and let me know if its DEFAULT or YML

Comment: On Showconfig.aspx is showing "YAML" which means that I was editing the wrong file. In my case, the correct file to change this setting is the "SerializationYaml.config". My problem was fixed. Thank you very much!